# How to get the list of people who do NOT have citizenship of country X in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the 3 following tables

**People**

| Id | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | 23 |
| 2 | John | 25 |
| 3 | Fred | 37 |
| 4 | Avery | 42 |

**Citizenship**

| Person_ID | Country_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |

**Country**

| Country_ID | Country_Name | Capital_City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UK | London |
| 2 | France | Paris |
| 3 | Canada | Ottawa |
| 4 | Australia | Canberra |
| 5 | Germany | Berlin |
| 6 | Russia | Moscow |

The goal here is to find all people who do NOT have French citizenship. My initial query was as follows

```
SELECT p.name
FROM  People p
          LEFT JOIN Citizenship ct
            ON p.id = ct.person_id
          LEFT JOIN Country c
            ON ct.country_id = c.country_id
WHERE c.country_name != 'France';
```

However, the result doesn't seem to be correct. What condition am I missing in this query?

Comment: We don't know what you mean by "doesn't seem to be correct".  What is the actual result and how is it different from what you expected? Also, sql syntax varies by vendor.  Always tag `sql` questions with your dbms and version as well

Comment: Side note, using `WHERE c.country_name != 'France';` implicitly converts your LEFT JOIN's into INNER JOIN's

Comment: The slow obvious way is to find everyone who lives in France and count them out `SELECT * FROM People WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Person_ID FROM Citizenship WHERE Country_ID = 2)`